# Laravel 5.7 Bootstrap 4 button color is weird

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I started new project in laravel 5.7 with bootstrap 4 but color of bootstrap buttons is weird
Here is picture:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Izmeni</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Prikaži</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is in my `<head>`:

```
...
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unos kompanije</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
```

How can I change color of my buttons so they would look same as one on bootstrap 4 website

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way You've bootrapped the project, the problems may be located into the [Bootstrap color SASS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults).
In general You may test to change those SASS variables for colors and then re-compile the SASS in your app.css file.
I also suggest You to see [Laravel From Scratch [Part 4] - Blade Templating & Compiling Assets](https://youtu.be/bSG2YMqJJys).

Comment: I didn't mess with that at all, previous project had normal colors, how can I have default colors?

Comment: Inspect the elements and find where the CSS property come from. Find a way to change this CSS property.

Comment: I found this `.btn-warning {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #ffed4a;
    border-color: #ffed4a;
}` So that means it is like that in my css file. But why?

Comment: app.css is the results of the SASS compiled. I don't know why the properties are set as they are set. See it as a challenge to dealing with Bootstrap SASS customization. Follow the Youtube video that I've posted above.

Comment: I did look at the video and followed what he did, but still my colors are same and I want to know why are they like that. How can I change it to original?

Comment: I need to see more. Please find a way to show me more code, possible at least an online version of the project, better the entire folder

Comment: well I don't know where to upload that file. But this css is from public/css/app.css even after i compiled it with npm it's still same. Is there any way where i can change that file or to download it?

Comment: You can Inspect the file, open in new window, download it and post here but is better to try to undersand where the CSS properties come from in the project, via inspector. The single file should be overrided.

Comment: [link](https://coreui.io/docs/components/buttons/) this site has same button color as mine.

Comment: So what's the problem? Use btn-* as you need, in this case you've used info and warning so blue and yellow. Change them to btn-primary if You need. In other cases please explain the problem better.

Comment: The problem is the color of buttons, why is it like that? its so bright, text on info button is black, and it's not same as one on bootstrap 4 website. I just want to have same colors as they do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default installation, then your `resources/sass/app.scss` file should look something like:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

The source of your woe is the `variables` import, so you have two options:

**Option 1.**
Completely remove `@import 'variables';`

**Option 2.**
Open `_variables.scss` (should be located in the same directory as `app.scss` and remove the block of color definitions. Should look something like:

```
$blue: #3490dc;
$indigo: #6574cd;
$purple: #9561e2;
$pink: #f66D9b;
$red: #e3342f;
$orange: #f6993f;
$yellow: #ffed4a;
$green: #38c172;
$teal: #4dc0b5;
$cyan: #6cb2eb;
```

Don't forget to recompile once you're done. ;)